# Does this multivariable derivative rule has an integral analogue?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose i have a derivable function $φ\in\mathcal{C}^1$ such that:
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}φ(f(t),g(t))=$$
$$\lim_{\text{d}t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\small φ(f(t+\text{d}t),g(t+\text{d}t))-φ(f(t),g(t))}{\text{d}t}$$
$$=φ^\prime(t)$$
Now, i'll show that:
$$φ^\prime(t)=\lim_{\text{d}t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\small φ(f(t+\text{d}t),g(t))-φ(f(t),g(t))}{\text{d}t}$$
$$+\lim_{\text{d}t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\small φ(f(t),g(t+\text{d}t))-φ(f(t),g(t))}{\text{d}t}$$
$$\Tiny=\lim_{\text{d}t\rightarrow0}\frac{φ(f(t+\text{d}t),g(t))+φ(f(t),g(t+\text{d}t))-2φ(f(t),g(t))}{\text{d}t}$$
By showing that the substitution $\text{d}t=2\text{d}x$ leaves the derivation unchanged:

Since $2\text{d}x\rightarrow0$ as $\text{d}x\rightarrow0$,
$$φ^\prime(t)≈\eta(x)$$
$$\Tiny=\lim_{\text{d}x\rightarrow0}\frac{φ(f(x+2\text{d}x),g(x))+φ(f(x),g(x+2\text{d}x))-2φ(f(x),g(x))}{2\text{d}x}$$
We can see that, for sufficiently small $\text{d}x$:
$$\small \eta(x)≈\frac{2φ(f(x+\text{d}x),g(x+\text{d}x))-2φ(f(x),g(x))}{2\text{d}x}$$
$$\small =\frac{φ(f(x+\text{d}x),g(x+\text{d}x))-φ(f(x),g(x))}{\text{d}x}$$
And so, $\text{d}x\rightarrow0$ implies:
$$\eta(x)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}φ(f(x),g(x))=φ^\prime(x)$$
This derivation rule proves very useful in taking derivatives of non-trivial functions, like $f(x)=x^x$. Is there some integration analogue of this kind as well?
Something like:
$$\int φ(f(t),g(t))\text{d}t=$$
$$\small \int φ(f(x),g(t))\text{d}x+\int φ(f(t),g(y))\text{d}y$$